# How to properly upload data to AdafruitIO with iteration (Python newbie)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, adafruit

I am quite a newbie to python and right now I am working on my first project. It is an application that is able to monitor air quality. It works fine to print the values to the screen. However, I encounter a problem when trying to upload the data to AdafruitIO. Here is my code:

```
from Adafruit_IO import Client, Feed, Data, RequestError
from outputs.output import Output
import requests

class AdafruitIO(Output):
    requiredData = ["ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY", "ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME"]
    optionalData = []

def __init__(self,data):
    self.ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY = data["ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY"]
    self.ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME = data["ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME"]
    
    
def outputData(self,dataPoints):
    aio = Client(self.ADAFRUIT_IO_USERNAME, self.ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY)
   
    for i in dataPoints:
        valName = i["name"]
        sensorkey = i["sensorkey"]
        value = i["value"]
        try:
            valName = aio.feeds(str(valName))
        except RequestError:
            feed = Feed(name = str(valName))
            valName = aio.create_feed(feed)
            
        aio.send_data(sensorkey, float(value))
```

And this is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 24, in outputData
    valName = aio.feeds(str(valName))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 274, in feeds
    return Feed.from_dict(self._get(path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 118, in _get
    self._handle_error(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 108, in _handle_error
    raise RequestError(response)
Adafruit_IO.errors.RequestError: Adafruit IO request failed: 404 Not Found - not found - that is an invalid URL, please check the API documentation at https://io.adafruit.com/api/docs to make sure your URL is correct

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxx.py", line 230, in <module>
    working = working and i.outputData(data)
  File "/home/pi/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.py", line 27, in outputData
    valName = aio.create_feed(feed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 285, in create_feed
    return Feed.from_dict(self._post(path, {"feed": feed._asdict()}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 127, in _post
    self._handle_error(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_IO/client.py", line 108, in _handle_error
    raise RequestError(response)
Adafruit_IO.errors.RequestError: Adafruit IO request failed: 404 Not Found - not found - that is an invalid URL, please check the API documentation at https://io.adafruit.com/api/docs to make sure your URL is correct
```

You help is really appreciated. Hope that its not too trivial.  I already got a headache because I really can't think of anything more to do here.

Best,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that I want to share with you, in case you have a similar problem. I post my data now via HTTP request:

```
import requests
from time import sleep
from outputs.output import Output

aio_key = "YOUR_ADAFRUIT_IO_KEY"
username = "YOUR_ADAFRUIT_USERNAME"

class AdafruitIO(Output):
    requiredData = []
    optionalData = []


    def __init__(self,data):
        pass


    def outputData(self,dataPoints):
        for i in dataPoints:
            url = 'https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/' + username + '/feeds/' + i["name"].lower() + '/data'

            body = {'value': str(i["value"])}
            headers = {'X-AIO-Key': aio_key, 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
            try:
                r = requests.post(url, json=body, headers=headers)
                print(r.text)
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
            sleep(5)
```